# Error "A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations." when retrieving data in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have this simple example code:

```
var request = mozIndexedDB.open('MyTestDatabase');
request.onsuccess = function(event){
  var db = event.target.result;
  var request = db.setVersion('1.0');
  request.onsuccess = function(event){
    console.log("Success version.");
    if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('customers')){
      console.log("Creating objectStore");
      db.createObjectStore('customers', {keyPath: 'ssn'});
    }
    var transaction = db.transaction([],  IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE, 2000);
    transaction.oncomplete = function(){
      console.log("Success transaction");
      var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customers');
    };
  };
};
```

I am getting this:

> A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations." code: "6

on line

```
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customers');
```

Can't figure out - what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the answer. I shouldn't access objectStore inside oncomplete. I just need to do it after making new transaction. Right way is this:

```
var transaction = db.transaction([],  IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE, 2000);
    transaction.oncomplete = function(){
      console.log("Success transaction");
    };
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customers');
```

Btw, this is how exactly Mozilla's MDN shows. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#section_10

Comment: This question is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149388/indexeddb-differences-between-onsuccess-and-oncomplete) regarding the differences between `onsuccess` and `oncomplete`

Answer (score 7):

You can create or delete an object store only in a versionchange transaction

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/IDBDatabase

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try that code but judging by [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IndexedDB_primer) you shouldn't pass an empty list as first parameter to `db.transaction()` - it should rather be `db.transaction(["customers"], ...)` because you want to work with that object store.

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't metter. I removed it for simplicity. So "customers" in scope doesn't change anything. Anyway, I think empty array is ok:
"If this parameter is unspecified, **empty**, or null, then the scope of the transaction is the entire connected database."

Comment: When I pass an empty array I get the error: "IDBDatabase.transaction: Empty scope passed in"