# Indexeddb: Differences between onsuccess and oncomplete?

Tags: javascript, database, indexeddb

I use two different events for the callback to respond when the IndexedDB transaction finishes or is successful:

Let's say... db : IDBDatabase object, tr : IDBTransaction object, os : IDBObjectStore object

```js
tr = db.transaction(os_name,'readwrite');
os = tr.objectStore();
```

case 1 :

```js
r = os.openCursor();
r.onsuccess = function() {
    if(r.result){
        callback_for_result_fetched();
        r.result.continue;
    } else {
        callback_for_transaction_finish();
    }
}
```

case 2:

```js
tr.oncomplete = callback_for_transaction_finish();
```

It is a waste if both of them work similarly. So can you tell me, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it's true these callbacks function similarly they are not the same: the difference between `onsuccess` and `oncomplete` is that transactions `complete` but requests, which are made on those transactions, are `successful`.

`oncomplete` is only defined in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBTransaction-oncomplete) as related to a transaction. A transaction doesn't have an `onsuccess` callback.

Comment: did you mean that when a transaction is complete, that doesn't mean the the whole processing is successful, innit?

Comment: yes, it means the transaction has gone out of scope and was committed

Answer (score 12):

Sorry for raising up quite an old thread, but it's questioning is a good starting point...

I've looked for a similar question but in a bit different use case and actually found no good answers or even a misleading ones.

Think of a use case when you need to make **several writes** into the objectStore of even into several ones. You definitely **don't want** to manage each single write and it's own success and error events. That is the meaning of transaction and this is the (proper) implementation of it for indexedDB:

```
var trx = dbInstance.transaction([storeIdA, storeIdB], 'readwrite'),
    storeA = trx.objectStore(storeIdA),
    storeB = trx.objectStore(storeIdB);

    trx.oncomplete = function(event) {
        // this code will run only when ALL of the following requests are succeed
        // and only AFTER ALL of them were processed
    };
    trx.onerror = function(error) {
        // this code will run if ANY of the following requests will fail
        // and only AFTER ALL of them were processed
    };

    storeA.put({ key:keyA, value:valueA });
    storeA.put({ key:keyB, value:valueB });
    storeB.put({ key:keyA, value:valueA });
    storeB.put({ key:keyB, value:valueB });
```

Clue to this understanding is to be found in the following statement of W3C [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBTransaction-oncomplete):

> To determine if a transaction has completed successfully, listen to the transaction’s **complete event rather than the success event of a particular request**, because the transaction may still fail after the success event fires.

Comment: just what i was looking for.  i assume objectStore.onsuccess, and objectStore.oncomplete  can also be used for multi .add, . get, .put, etc... on given objectstore.

Answer (score 2):

I would only caution that there is no garentee that getting a successful trx.oncomplete means the data was written to the disk/database:

We are seeing a problem with trx.oncomplete where the data is not being written to the db on disk. FireFox has an explanation of what they did that is causing this problem here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction/oncomplete

It seems that windows/edge is also having the same issue. Basically, there is no guarantee that your app will have data written to the database, if/when the user decides to kill or power down the device. We've even tried waiting up to 15 minutes before shutting down in some cases and haven't seen the data written. For me I'd always want to ensure that a data write completes and is committed.

Are there other solutions for a real persistent database, or enhancements to the IndexedDB beyond FF experimental add...